# Clicking on thumbnail doesn't update main image

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#minipics img').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#mainPic img').attr('src', url);
    });
```

I have this little code for image gallery. I want to insert also jquery tabs under the gallery.

so I have HTML for it:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a  href="#tabs-1">პროდუქტის აღწერა</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">პრომო ვიდეო</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">მსგავსი პროდუქტი</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4">კომენტარები (0)</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1" class="ui-widget-content1">
<p>1</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2" class="ui-widget-content1">
<p>2</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3" class="ui-widget-content1">
<p>3</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-4" class="ui-widget-content1">
<p>4</p>
</div>
</div>
```

also I'm inserting table ui.

when I'm inserting function:

```
 $(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

tabs work, but my gallery doesn't work. What may be a problem here?

this is gallery html:

```
<div id='mainPic'>
        <img src="img/a1.png">
    </div>
        </div>
    <div id='minipics'>
        <img src="img/a1.png">
        <img src="img/a2.png">
        <img src="img/a3.png">
        <img src="img/a4.png">
        <img src="img/a5.png">
        <img src="img/a6.png">
        <img src="img/a7.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: Your tabs work but your gallery doesn't but you've only given us the html for the tabs! What is mainPic? Does the gallery work without the tabs?

Comment: I edited and wrote gallery html. yes gallery works without this
 $(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is the solution but I'd recommend using a `.on` function instead of `.click`, only because I find them to work more frequently in my projects.

```
$('#minipics img').on( "click", function() {
   var url = $(this).attr('src');
   $('#mainPic img').attr('src', url);
});
```